# Can I use “everything” after a list?

Tags: word-usage, punctuation

I want to describe something by saying it can do or has this and this and that, then putting the focus that it can do or has literally everything. Here’s an example:

> He has it all—money, a good family, decent education,**...everything**.

Can **everything** fit in that place? What about my punctuation?

Answer (score 2):

"Everything" can be used in such a sentence to provide emphasis. However, the punctuation you have provided does not seem too natural; usually there is not an ellipsis located directly after a comma. Below are some punctuation schemes that may appear more natural.

> He has it all — money, a good family, decent education . . . everything.
>
> He has it all — money, a good family, decent education — everything.
>
> He has it all — money, a good family, decent education, everything.

The first two schemes put slightly more emphasis on "everything" by separating it from the rest of the items in the list.